# get today's date in format "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00". Strange behavior of date conversion

Tags: php, date, time

I'm trying to find the format yyyy-mm-dd with zero seconds (the time, when the date changes) for time() function. So, for today that would be "2012-06-07 00:00:00".
Seems like everything is clear, but

```
    $today_starts_str='2012-06-07 00:00:00';
    var_dump($today_starts_str); //'2012-06-07 00:00:00', good

    $today_starts_sec=strtotime ( $today_starts_str );
    var_dump($today_starts_sec); //1339016400, good

    $today_starts_str2=date ( 'Y-m-d h:m:s', $today_starts_sec );
    var_dump($today_starts_str2); //"2012-06-07 12:06:00" Why it is 12:06, but not 00:00?
```

So, i need something to get a time when the date changes for any time (probably using time());

Comment: You are using the wrong parameters in your date() call. See http://php.net/date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `m` inside a date format string is for the month, use `i` for the minutes ;-)

And for 24-hour format of an hour, use `H` instead of `h`. (Thanks Emil!)

Comment: And `h` is for twelve-hour-clock

Answer (score 3):

Try `$today_starts_str2=date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $today_starts_sec );`